# MAVEN_OPTS proxy settings not reflected when running mvn help:effective-settings - how do I stop mvn from using SOCKS proxy defined by system?

Tags: macos, maven, proxy, maven-surefire-plugin, socks

I'm trying to stop maven 3.3.9 (running on Mac OS 10.12.3 and Java 1.8.0_121) from using a SOCKS proxy defined in System Preferences.

I have removed all `proxy` elements from my `settings.xml`.

In my `.bash_profile`, I have set the following:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 \
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.example.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 \
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|foo.example.com|*.bar.example.com|*.baz.example.com \
-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost|foo.example.com|*.bar.example.com|*.baz.example.com \
-DsocksProxyHost -DsocksProxyPort"
```

When I run `mvn help:effective-settings`, I get the following:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">/java/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <servers xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <!-- ... -->
  </servers>
  <mirrors xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://nexus.example.com:nnnn/...</url>
      <id>nexus</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases />
          <snapshots />
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases />
          <snapshots />
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>nexus</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <pluginGroups xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

**As you can see, it doesn't contain a `proxy` section at all. Does that mean it's not picking up the proxy settings from the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable?**

The actual issue is that we have a SOCKS proxy setting defined in System Preferences (which I don't want to deactivate), but while that is on, maven builds (i.e. JUnit integration tests) fail (`Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SOCKS: Connection not allowed by ruleset`). Once deactivated, the build passes.

So I want to override the system settings for maven, disabling SOCKS proxy settings. Yet it doesn't look like it reads the overrides?

I also tried to set a SOCKS proxy in my maven `settings.xml`, but that didn't have the desired effect either (presumably because you can either not set SOCKS proxies in `settings.xml`, or because you can't exclude hosts from socks proxies (there is no equivalent `-D` option available)):

```
<proxy>
  <id>no-socks-proxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>socks</protocol>
  <host>socksproxy.example.com</host>
  <port>nnnn</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>*</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Any idea what I need to do to stop maven from picking up the system SOCKS settings?

**Update**

I just checked, and Terminal says the following is being executed:

```
java '-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.example.com’ '-Dhttp.proxyPort=80' '-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.example.com’ '-Dhttps.proxyPort=80' '-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|…’ '-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost|…’ -DsocksProxyHost -DsocksProxyPort -classpath /.../apache-maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar '-Dclassworlds.conf=/.../apache-maven/bin/m2.conf' '-Dmaven.home=/.../apache-maven' '-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/.../foo/trunk/bar’ org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean install

...

java '-javaagent:/.../.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/.../foo/trunk/bar/baz/target/jacoco.exec' -jar /.../foo/trunk/bar/baz/target/surefire/surefirebooternnnnnnn.jar /.../foo/trunk/bar/baz/target/surefire/surefirennnnnnntmp /.../foo/trunk/bar/baz/target/surefire/surefire_nnnnntmp
```

That makes me think that the settings do get picked up by the parent `mvn` process, but that they don't get passed on to child processes (i.e. `surefire`).

Incidentally, setting `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost -DsocksProxyPort"` forces them into the child processes, and my build passes (whereas setting `export JAVA_OPTS="-DsocksProxyHost -DsocksProxyPort"` has no effect).

Is there a way to force the `JAVA_OPTIONS` into maven's child processes, without using [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) (and without changing the POM as per [surefire manual](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html))?

Comment: What about using `<nonProxyHosts>*.*</nonProxyHosts>`?

Comment: Well, in our corporate network, we often refer to servers just by their host name, without domain or domain ending. So I think the dot would be wrong?

Comment: I believe that maven expects a string for nonProxyHosts and that the wildcard alone won't be enough, that's why I thought it would be worth a try

Comment: Sadly, no luck: `[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Network error IOException: SOCKS: Connection not allowed by ruleset)>`